# Way to alternate table row colours with inconsistent classes with css

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

I was wondering whether css is sophisticated enough to alternate table row colours with a class in a table structure that includes other classes.  Take for example:

```
<table>
<tr class="alt">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="differentClass">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="alt">
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="differentClass">
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So what I would like to do is alternate the rows with the class "alt" only.

I have tried

```
table tr.alt:nth-child(even)
```

View this fiddle and you'll see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/6mTSP/. The "And again" row should be white not grey.

Perhaps its not possible with a CSS only solution?

Comment: You're looking for something like `:nth-of-class()` which does not exist. There's more likely a better way to structure your markup.

Comment: There certainly is a better way, but alas this is what I have to work with :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not *currently* possible with a CSS-only solution.  Until CSS allows combinations of pseudo-selectors or has another pseudo-selector created specifically as mentioned in the comments, this would require JavaScript.